# Navigation bar overlapping content text

Tags: navigation, position, z-index, overlap, overlapping

my content text is being overlapped by my navigation bar. I have looked at other questions like this, but i have not been able to fix this. 
 I think that it might be because of my "z-indexes". I need the functionality of the page to stay somewhat the same as now, i just need to be able to see the top of the content text. 

I believe that the code i have put in here should be enough to see what the solution to this problem could be.

```css
p, div, a
{
    font-family: "Century", sans-serif;
}

ul 
{
 list-style-type: none;
}

li
 {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 15px;
}

nav
{
 text-align: center;
}

img 
{
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
}

.content
 {
 z-index: -10;
 position: fixed;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
}

.textbox
 {
 z-index: -5;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 11%;
 margin-top: 1%;
 text-align: left;
 color: #000000;
}

.rubrik
{
 font-size: 35px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.brod
{
 font-size: 18px;
}

.header
{
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 25px #000000;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

body
{
 margin: 0;
}

html
{
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li> <a href="index.php">FORSIDE</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="nyheder.php">NYHEDER</a> </li>
     <li> <a class="currentpage" href="hvem-er-vi.php">HVEM ER VI?</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="om-moellevangen.php">OM MØLLEVANGEN</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="vaerdigrundlag.php">VÆRDIGRUNDLAG</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="vedtaegter.php">VEDTÆGTER</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="galleri.php">GALLERI</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="kontakt.php">KONTAKT</a> </li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
   <img src="files/forside3.png"/>
  </div> 
  
<div class="textbox">
 <p class="rubrik">
 Bestyrelsen
 </p>

 <p class="brod">
 Formand:</br>
 Anne, Galsted</br>
 Tlf: </br>
 Mobil: </br>
 </br>
 Næstformand:</br>
 Niels, Agerskov</br>
 Tlf: </br>
 Mobil: </br>
 </br>
 </p>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source code is not formatted well in here but in these cases I add a padding-top to the container or a margin-top to the child.

e.g. (you need to choose a better class name than textbox but anyway)

```
div.textbox
{
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have also renamed my classes to better names.